# To list the users within the radius which is given by the user as dynamic based on lat and long

Tags: mysql

I have used below query in PHPMYADMIN to list the users based on lat and long within X km.  But, I got the below error. My mysql version is 5.6

Query :

```
SELECT 

( ATAN ( SQRT( POW( COS( RADIANS( markers.lat ) )  SIN( RADIANS( markers.lng ) - RADIANS( -122 ) ) , 2 ) + POW( COS( RADIANS( 37 ) )  SIN( RADIANS( markers.lat ) ) - SIN( RADIANS( 37 ) )  COS( RADIANS( markers.lat ) )  COS( RADIANS( markers.lng ) - RADIANS( -122 ) ) , 2 ) ) , SIN( RADIANS( -122 ) )  SIN( RADIANS( markers.lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( 37 ) )  COS( RADIANS( markers.lat ) )  COS( RADIANS( markers.lng ) - RADIANS( -122 ) ) ) 6371000) AS distance, markers.id FROM markers ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( RADIANS( markers.lng ) - RADIANS( -122 ) ) , 2 ) + POW( COS( RADIANS( 37 ) ) ' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in the code.  For instance, this is not valid SQL:

```
POW( COS( RADIANS( 37 ) ) SIN( RADIANS( markers.lat ) )
```

You need a comma, but that's not the right formula.  I would suggest that you start over with a working query and substitute in your variables.

Comment: Even, I tried as per the below link (google map api detail), I didnt get any error, but, result is empty. 

https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#findnearsql

SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: Remove the `HAVING` and see if you agree with the results you see.